# SwiftUI button doesn't recognize button's frame

Tags: button, swiftui

[image: 1]

When I try to change the background color of the button it only changes the color of the surrounding area?

Comment: Try to set button style plain and post code instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

Set the shape. For example

```
.contentShape(Circle())
```

or

```
.contentShape(Rectangle())
```